# XML table editor

Tags: xml, xml-serialization, xml-editor

I need a 2D tables editor, that:

1. Let's rename columns.
2. Can save data as XML, using column names as tags, so it's possible to deserialize this XML and get collection of struct instances.
3. Supports implicit typing for columns, and if column has no type -- for every cell as well (it should be serialized as <MyColumn xsi:type="xsd:double">0.5</MyColumn>). Types should be shown on the same table (different colors or prefix or suffix etc.).

I want the tool for unit tests. 10 columns table, written in the tests code, looks ugly.

Comment: in which programming language?
what are the environment requirements?

Comment: I think, it's not important. Correct XML with implicit typing (when required) is suppported everywhere. I use C#.

Comment: Would like that too! did you find anything so far?

Comment: @Ted Unfortunately, nope.